# Symfony2 REST API implementation with session authentication on AJAX login

Tags: ajax, symfony

I'm using Symfony2 (version 2.3) and trying to create a REST API on the server side that works with a JS client (which is a bookmarklet I can inject on any web page).

For the moment I have implemented:

- A login action. I sent the _user/_password values directly to the login_check action. I tuned this setting 'success_handler' and 'failure_handler' so I can write a custom response message indicating if the login was fine (specially for login failure sending a 404 message instead of redirecting to the login page).
  The idea was to start a session without the need of a login form page.
- A set of actions with GET, POST and PUT methods.

I'm using the Postman REST Client plugin for chrome and all seems to work fine with my tests.

The problem is once logged via AJAX when I call a POST action from my client application the POST action is cancelled. Looking at Symfony log I see the next message:

```
[2013-07-15 08:17:01] security.INFO: Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point (A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.) [] []
```

Seems like I'm not logged in at all and I'm redirected to the login form page. On Chrome I see the POST action is cancelled. On FF I get a 302 HTTP code (redirect).

On the other side I use Postman REST client plugin for chrome to test my API and it seems to works fine.
The only difference I can see when using Postman is come cookies are sent to the server while when I inject the client JS code on a remote page the cookies seems not to be sent.

*NOTE: My API takes into account same domain policy for AJAX request (using Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Methods on sever side).*

Any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,
I finally take a different approach to solve it. Let some comment here because if they can help someone.

The problem is my JS client is injected in a web page as a DIV element. That result the code is living in a page with a different domain than it was loaded.

I change this to inject an iframe pointing to my code. This way the code isn't really injected in the page and lives in the same domain it was loaded.

Using an iframe the sessions works fine.

Thanks for your time.